# Stack overflow when using Haskell sort function

Tags: haskell

I am implementing a filter in Haskell, i.e. a program that I can call from the command-line as follows:

```
$ cat inputfile.txt | myFilter > outputfile.txt
```

When running the program on a file of about 80 MB, I get a stack overflow
(Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.). I am using GHC Version 6.12.3 under cygwin.

I think the problem comes from the `sort` function that I am using in the program, but after I have been looking for the problem for three days I have no clue how to solve this so I would like if someone could give me a hint.

Here are the essential details about my program.

My filter program reads standard input into a string, splits it into lines and parses each line into a record of some type `Event`

```
data Event = ...
```

which is an instance of `Ord`

```
instance Ord Event where
    x < y = ...
```

so that I can sort events using the built-in `sort` function.

Splitting into lines and parsing the events (one event per line) is performed by a function

```
p :: String -> [Event]
```

which internally uses the standard function `lines`.

I also have a function g that groups events:

```
g :: [Event] -> [[Event]]
```

g uses some criteria that are not relevant here; each group can contain at most 4 events.

I sort each group of events (represented as a list) using `sort` (i.e., all events inside each group get sorted), and finally format the all event groups as a string using a function

```
f :: [[Event]] -> String
```

The main function looks as follows:

```
main = interact (f . (map sort) . g . p)
```

As said, running this program on a file of about 80 MB gives a stack overflow.

If I replace the sort function with the following function (a naive quick sort implementation):

```
mySort :: [Event] -> [Event]
mySort [] = []
mySort (e:es) = let h = [j | j <- es, j < e]
                    t = [j | j <- es, e < j]
                in
                  (mySort h) ++ [e] ++ (mySort t)


main = interact (f . (map mySort) . g . p)
```

I have no stack overflow!

If in the function `mySort` I replace the definition of `t` with the following:

```
                    t = [j | j <- es, e <= j]
```

i.e. I replace `<` with `<=`, the stack overflow is there again!

So I have no clue of what is going here.
I cannot see that I have introduced any infinite recursion. My other hypothesis is that lazy evaluation can play a role here (does `<=` produce a bigger thunk than `<`?).

I have some experience with Haskell but I am no real expert so I would be glad to get some useful hint because I have been struggling to understand this for the past three days.

Comment: I had posted this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com and, since it is off-topic there, I have moved it to this site. Before I could delete the question from there I got a hint to read http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow, which I am also doing right now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The culprit is

```
instance Ord Event where
    x < y = ...
```

which is the wrong way to define an `Ord` instance. The minimal complete definition of an `Ord` instance defines one of `compare` or `(<=)`. There are default definitions of `compare` in terms of `(<=)`, and of all `Ord` member functions in terms of `compare`. So if you define `(<)`, that's the only `Ord` member you can use, all others will loop infinitely when called, since they call `compare`, which calls `(<=)`, which calls `compare` ...

The `Data.List.sort` function uses `compare` to determine the order, so it loops at the first comparison. Your custom quicksort only uses `(<)`, so that works.

Comment: +1: Thanks a lot for the answer. By implementing `<=` instead of `<` I get the correct result and no overflow. As a side note: my type Event is also an instance of Eq and so there is a `== :: Event -> Event -> Bool`; but this is not sufficient, one has to implement `<=` (or `compare`).

Comment: I wish `Eq`, `Ord`, etc. just required some arbitrary method to be implemented (e.g: `(==)` and `(<)`) and had all the others be ordinary functions.  This would give a standard way to define instances and avoid all the trouble.  The only downside of not being free to define `(>)`, `(/=)`, or `compare` seems minuscule in comparison. Especially as long as Haskell has no static checking for the validity of the set of methods implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying out to profile the code and to get quick result - try to increase stack size.

Compile your program with enabling RTS and specify desired stack size.

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html